# Disable uninitialized warning for a local variable

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, initialization, compiler-warnings

C++ compilers emit warnings when a local variable may be uninitialized on first usage. However, sometimes, I know that the variable will always be written before being used, so I do not need to initialize it. When I do this, the compiler emits a warning, of course. Since my team is building with `-Werror`, the code will not compile. How can I turn off this warning for specific local variables. I have the following restrictions:

1. I am not allowed to change compiler flags
2. The solution must work on all compilers (i.e., no gnu-extensions or other compiler specific attributes)
3. I want to use this only on specific local variables. Other uninitialized locals should still trigger a warning
4. The solution should not generate any instructions.
5. I cannot alter the class of the local variable. I.e., I cannot simply add a "do nothing" constructor.

Of course, the easiest solution would be to initialize the variable. However, the variable is of a type that is costly to initialize (even default initialization is costly) and the code is used in a very hot loop, so I do not want to waste the CPU cycles for an initialization that is guaranteed to be overwritten before it is read anyway.

So is there a platform-independent, compiler-independent way of telling the compiler that a local variable does not need to be initialized?

Here is some example code that might trigger such a warning:

```
void foo(){
    T t;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
       if (i == 0) t = ...;
       if (i == 1) doSomethingWith(t);
    }
}
```

As you see, the first loop cycle initializes t and the second one uses it, so t will never be read uninitialized. However, the compiler is not able to deduce this, so it emits a warning. Note that this code is quite simplified for the sake of brevity.

Comment: " I do not want to waste the CPU cycles for an initialization that is guaranteed to be overwritten before it is read anyway." Usually GCC would not warn then... the system is not perfect, but quite good.

Comment: @gexicide you can create a special empty constructor with a flag and use that for initialization avoid costly computation of the normal construcotr: `HeavyClass obj(kFlagNone)`

Comment: @deviantfan: It does. Otherwise, I would not be asking here :). And even if GCC does not, another compiler might warn.

Comment: @Raxvan: The class used is out of my reach. I cannot add code to it. Thanks for mentioning, I added this restriction to my list.

Comment: @gexicide, why not initialize `t` outside of the loop, then have the loop start at `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: the code you posted doesn't give any warnings.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Because it is too simplified so *your* (not necessarily every) compiler is able to deduce things correctly.

Comment: I could figure out that much. Still, it would be nice to see an actual example.

Comment: @gexicide do you reffer to the warning `potentially uninitialized local variable 't' used` ?

Comment: @gexicide: Yeah, I think so

Comment: "platform-independent, compiler-independent" - nope. my advice: be more pragmatic.

Comment: @gexicide given your example try to make `t` of type `Data<T> t` where `Data` is `template <class T>struct Data { T value; Data(){} };` and use `t.value` instead of `t`. This appears to remove the warning on visual studio

Comment: It's really tricky but you could define a function looking like that: `inline void _uninitialized_variable (...) { }` and then create a `UNINITIALIZED` macro calling this function with the address of your variable: `#define UNINITIALIZED(v) _uninitialized_variable (&v) ;`. Then `T t; UNINITIALIZED(t)`. The compiler will see the call as a `out` parameter (initializing your variable). I said it: This is really trick (I would not use it in my own code).

Comment: First check that the compiler really is not right. If you are sure, then the problem is that you try to obey to coding guidelines and the compiler is fighting you because it gives false warnings. Don't stick to the rules, disable the compiler warning (maybe platform specific in the code) or live with the performance loss. Don't fight the tool. And don't assume that you can write nice code that will never issue a warning on any compiler.

Comment: @WernerHenze: 'Disable compiler warnigs'. You just can't do this in a project where other people compile your code and the company mandates that `-Werror` is used... Right now, I do live with the performance loss, but I measured it to be almost 23%, so it would be really nice to get rid of it!

Comment: Another reason *not* to add a useless initializer is that it can inhibit warnings from checking tools. If there's a bug in the code and the variable really is accessed before it's initialized, a separate tool can catch it; if you add a dummy initializer, the tool has no way of knowing that the initializer gives it a value that shouldn't be used.

Comment: @WarnerHenze are you sure that the variable is not actually read? It's hard to imagine how a function so small that a single setting of a variable to 0 reduces performance by 23%, yet the compiler cannot deduce that this setting can be optimized out since it is never read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer will recommend another approach: instead of disabling the warning code, just do some reformulation on the implementation. I see two approaches:

**First Option**

You can use pointers instead of a real object and guarantee that it will be initialized just when you need it, something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> t;
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
   if(i == 0) if(t.empty()) t = std::unique_ptr<T>(new T); *t = ...;
   if(i == 1) if(t.empty()) t = std::unique_ptr<T>(new T); doSomethingWith(*t);
}
```

It's interesting to note that probably when `i==0`, you don't need to construct `t` using the default constructor. I can't guess how your `operator=` is implemented, but I supose that probably you are assigning an object that's already allocated in the code that you are omitting in the `...` segment.

---

**Second Option**

As your code experiences such a huge performance loss, I can infer that T will never be an basic tipe (ints, floats, etc). So, instead of using pointers, you can reimplement your class T in a way that you use an init method and avoid initializing it on the constructor. You can use some boolean to indicate if the class needs initalization or not:

```
class FooClass()
{
public:
   FooClass() : initialized(false){ ... }

   //Class implementation
void init()
{
   //Do your heavy initialization code here.
   initialized = true;
}

bool initialized() const { return initialized; }

private:
   bool initialized;
}
```

Than you will be able to write it like this:

```
T t;
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
   if(i == 0) if(!t.initialized()) t.init(); t = ...;
   if(i == 1) if(!t.initialized()) t.init(); doSomethingWith(t);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. However, the implementation of T is out of my scope in a third party library. I cannot change it.

Comment: @gexicide check my edited answer.. does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

If the code is not very complex, I usually unroll one of the iterations:

```
void foo(){
  T t;
  t = ...;
  for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
    doSomethingWith(t);
  }
}
```